# Append child elements in parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div id = "a"></div>
<div id = "b"></div>
<div id = "ab"><div>

function addKids() 
{
    img1 = document.createElement("img");
    img1.src = // SOURCE1;
    document.getElementById("a").appendChild(a);

    img2 = document.createElement("img");
    img2.src = // SOURCE2;
    document.getElementById("b").appendChild(b);

    document.getElementById("ab").appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById("ab").appendChild(b);
}
```

This is what I want, Basically I want img1 in div A, img 2 in div B, and then both images in div AB. If I remove the code to appendChildren to AB, the images show up in their respective divs, but once the appendChildren is there, they only appear in AB. How can I make the images appear in each div correctly without too much extra coding?

Also, more images will constantly be added to div A and B. How can I get the last image of both divs into div AB?

Thanks!

Comment: Any given node can only be the child of one element at a time. The `.appendChild()` method does not make a copy of the node.

Comment: See [MDN: Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):  " If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).

This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM elements can't be shared by different parents, cause that the last parent `AB` will be the only one for image `a` and `b`

An alternative is cloning these images using the function [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```js
function addKids() {
  a = document.createElement("img");
  a.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2FO1.jpg?s=48&g=1';
    document.getElementById("a").appendChild(a);

  b = document.createElement("img");
  b.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-w_IWeYU4ynw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAF0/Xbzx7yhjooQ/photo.jpg?sz=48';
    document.getElementById("b").appendChild(b);

  var ab = document.getElementById("ab");
  ab.appendChild(a.cloneNode());
  ab.appendChild(b.cloneNode());
}

addKids();
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="ab">ab
  <div>
```

Comment: jesus christ tysm! Also referring to the second part of my question, I can just cloneNode the LastChild right? Or should LastElementChild? Actually, wouldn't either work?